Indexed items not showing in Content Collection
I have an entity called "Degree":

I have a source that retrieves 92 items successfully.

Inside of sources configuration, I have the following settings:
Tags definition

Document Extractor

Document Extractor code
function extract(request, response) {
    $ = response.body;
    url = request.url;
    id = url.replace(/[/:.]/g, '_');

    return [{
        'id': id,
        'title': $('title').text(),
        'name': $('meta[name="og:title"]').attr('content') || 'Title not set',
        'description': $('meta[name="og:description"]').attr('content') || 'Description not set',
        'type': $('meta[name="og:type"]').attr('content') || 'website_content',
        'tags': $('meta[name="tags"]').attr('content') || 'Tags not set',
        'footer_tags': $('meta[name="footer_tags"]').attr('content') || 'Footer Tags not set',
    }];
}

Like I said earlier, 92 items indexed successfully. When I am trying to see indexed content under Content Collection > Degree, there is no content indexed.

I don't know why, did I miss something?
Thank you.

It works now, after a few tests, "Tags" under "Tags definition" should be "content".

By changing that to content, you are not indexing and mapping to the 'degree' entity which seems to be the focus of your question.

Yes, if you look at Document Extractor, screenshot above, entity points to "degree"

From what you have posted, I cant see anything that is mapping the incoming 'indexed' items to your 'degree' entity.
So the crawler is successfully finding 92 items, but not mapping any successfully.
If you look to the far right of "degree card" on the image you have labelled "tags definition", you should see an option to edit.

If you click that, it should open up an editer where you define the JS Source code for extracting the content.
You need to then add something like this:
// Sample extractor function. Change the function to suit your individual needs
function extract(request, response) {
    $ = response.body;

    return [{
        'description': $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content') || $('meta[property="og:description"]').attr('content') || $('p').text(),
        'name': $('meta[name="title"]').attr('content'),
        'type': 'video',
        'url': $('meta[property="og:url"]').attr('content'),
        'image': $('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content')
    }];
}

Making sure to map items that are guaranteed to be on every page being indexed. Otherwise you need to provide a default.
Please try that out and let me know.

Hi, I updated the answer with document extractor code.
